# controller fails to initialize

Tags: ros, microcontroller, gazebo, plugin, controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hallo!

I've created a simple joint-controller as described in this tutorial: [link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_mechanism/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20realtime%20joint%20controller)

Here is the code
robocv_controller_file.h

```
   #include <pr2_controller_interface/controller.h>
   #include <pr2_mechanism_model/joint.h>

   namespace my_controller_ns{

   class MyControllerClass: public pr2_controller_interface::Controller
    {
      private:
       pr2_mechanism_model::JointState* left_wheel_state_;
         pr2_mechanism_model::JointState* right_wheel_state_;
         double init_pos1_;
         double init_pos2_;

     public:
     virtual bool init(pr2_mechanism_model::RobotState *robot,
                  ros::NodeHandle &n);
      virtual void starting();
       virtual void update();
      virtual void stopping();
    };
    }
```

robocv_controller_file.cpp

#include "robocv_controller/robocv_controller_file.h"
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>

namespace my_controller_ns {

/// Controller initialization in non-realtime
bool MyControllerClass::init(pr2_mechanism_model::RobotState *robot,
ros::NodeHandle &n)
{
std::string left_wheel, right_wheel;

```
 if (!n.getParam("left_wheel", left_wheel))
 {
   ROS_ERROR("No joint given in namespace: '%s')",
             n.getNamespace().c_str());
   return false;
 }

 left_wheel_state_ = robot->getJointState(left_wheel);
 if (!left_wheel_state_)
 {
   ROS_ERROR("MyController could not find joint named '%s'",
             left_wheel.c_str());
   return false;
 }
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
if (!n.getParam("right_wheel", right_wheel))
{
ROS_ERROR("No joint given in namespace: '%s')",
n.getNamespace().c_str());
return false;
}

```
 right_wheel_state_ = robot->getJointState(right_wheel);
 if (!right_wheel_state_)
 {
   ROS_ERROR("MyController could not find joint named '%s'",
             right_wheel.c_str());
   return false;
 }
 return true;
```

}

/// Controller startup in realtime
void MyControllerClass::starting()
{
init_pos1_ = left_wheel_state_->position_;
init_pos2_ = right_wheel_state_->position_;
}

/// Controller update loop in realtime
void MyControllerClass::update()
{
double desired_pos = init_pos1_ + 15 * sin(ros::Time::now().toSec());
double current_pos = left_wheel_state_->position_;
left_wheel_state_->commanded_effort_ = -10 * (current_pos - desired_pos);
right_wheel_state_->commanded_effort_ = -10 * (current_pos - desired_pos);
}

/// Controller stopping in realtime
void MyControllerClass::stopping()
{}
} // namespace
PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(controller,MyControllerPlugin,
my_controller_ns::MyControllerClass,
pr2_controller_interface::Controller)

It works fine. Then i wrote another one:

```
   #include <pr2_controller_interface/controller.h>
   #include <pr2_mechanism_model/joint.h>

    namespace my_controller_ns{

    class MyControllerClass: public pr2_controller_interface::Controller
    {
     private:
      pr2_mechanism_model::JointState* joint_state_;
      double init_pos_;

      public:
      virtual bool init(pr2_mechanism_model::RobotState *robot,
                 ros::NodeHandle &n);
       virtual void starting();
       virtual void update();
       virtual void stopping();
        };
        }
```

And appropriate C++ file:

```
#include "wheel_controller/wheel_controller_file.h"
```

#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>

namespace my_controller_ns {

/// Controller initialization in non-realtime
bool MyControllerClass::init(pr2_mechanism_model::RobotState *robot,
ros::NodeHandle &n)
{
std::string joint_name;
if (!n.getParam("/joint_name", joint_name))
{
ROS_ERROR("No joint given in namespace: '%s')",
n.getNamespace().c_str());
return false;
}

```
 joint_state_ = robot->getJointState(joint_name);
 if (!joint_state_)
 {
   ROS_ERROR("MyController could not find joint named '%s'",
             joint_name.c_str());
   return false;
 }
 return true;
```

}

/// Controller startup in realtime
void MyControllerClass::starting()
{
init_pos_ = joint_state_->position_;
}

/// Controller update loop in realtime
void MyControllerClass::update()
{
double desired_pos = init_pos_ + 15 * sin(ros::Time::now().toSec());
double current_pos = joint_state_->position_;
joint_state_->commanded_effort_ = -10 * (current_pos - desired_pos);
}

/// Controller stopping in realtime
void MyControllerClass::stopping()
{}
} // namespace

PLUGINLIB_DECLARE_CLASS(wheel_controller,MyControllerPlugin,
my_controller_ns::MyControllerClass,
pr2_controller_interface::Controller)

When i'm trying to load the second controller rxconsole shows me this error:

```
Node: /gazebo
Time: 1365.017000000
Severity: Error
Location: /home/robot/peter_workspace/sandbox/controller        /src/robocv_controller_file.cpp:MyControllerClass::init:16
 Published Topics: /rosout, /tf, /gazebo/paused, /clock, /gazebo/link_states, /    gazebo/model_states, /gazebo/parameter_descriptions, /gazebo/parameter_updates,   /joint_states, /mechanism_statistics

 No joint given in namespace: '/wheel_controller')
```

For some reason it refers to robocv_controller source file.
rospack plugins shows that both plugins are registered:

```
robot@Robot2:~/peter_workspace/sandbox/wheel_controller$ rospack plugins --attrib=plugin pr2_controller_interface
controller /home/robot/peter_workspace/sandbox/controller/controller_plugins.xml
velocity_controller /home/robot/peter_workspace/sandbox/velocity_controller/controller_plugins.xml
wheel_controller /home/robot/peter_workspace/sandbox/wheel_controller/controller_plugins.xml
ethercat_trigger_controllers /opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_controllers/ethercat_trigger_controllers/controller_plugins.xml
pr2_calibration_controllers /opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_controllers/pr2_calibration_controllers/controller_plugins.xml
pr2_mechanism_controllers /opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_controllers/pr2_mechanism_controllers/controller_plugins.xml
 robot_mechanism_controllers /opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_controllers/robot_mechanism_controllers/controller_plugins.xml
 pr2_controller_manager /opt/ros/electric/stacks/pr2_mechanism/pr2_controller_manager/test/controller_plugin.xml
```

Please, help. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42485/controller-fails-to-initialize/) by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) on ROS Answers with karma: 338 on 2012-08-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2014-08-20**:
Can you tell us your solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Problem solved.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Listov](https://answers.ros.org/users/3071/peter-listov/) with karma: 338 on 2012-08-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ros_user](https://answers.ros.org/users/23239/ros_user/) on 2015-08-28**:
HOW have you solved it?